# How distinct works in sql?

Tags: sql

I tried to understand how the distinct (and therefore distinct count) work.
I have a data with:

```
Sessionid, User_solici, code
```

While within 1 `SessionID` there is 1 `User_solici`. However, there could be multiple `SessionID` for the same `User_solici`.

For `User_solici` of "a", I have `Session = 1, 55` and `null`.

I want to find distinct `SessionID` where (code = 7 and code = 1) OR (code = 7 and code = 2) for the same `User_solici`.

My query is complete.

```
create table mytable 
(
    sessionid varchar(255),
    User_solici varchar(255),
    code varchar(255)
);

insert into mytable (sessionid, User_solici, code)
values 
('1', 'a', '7'),
('1', 'a', '1'),
('1', 'a', '2'),
('1', 'a', '999'),
('2', 'b', '7'),
('2', 'b', '1'),
('2', 'b', '2'),
('2', 'b', '999'),
('55', 'a', '7'),
('55', 'a', '1'),
('55', 'a', '2'),
('', 'a', '7'),
('', 'a', '1'),
('', 'a', '2'),
('', 'c', '7'),
('', 'c', '1'),
('', 'c', '2');

select distinct 
    T1.sessionid
from 
    mytable T1 
join 
    mytable T2 on T1.User_solici = T2.User_solici
               and T1.code = '7' 
               and T2.code in ('1', '2');

select 
    T1.sessionid, 
    T1.User_solici, 
    T1.code as T1code, 
    T2.code as T2code
from 
    mytable T1 
join 
    mytable T2 on T1.User_solici = T2.User_solici
               and T1.code = '7' 
               and T2.code in ('1', '2');
```

But I try to understand what SQL does.

Look at the raw table, I see 5 sessionid (1,a), (2,b), (55,a),  (,a) (,c) that satisfy.

OR I can argue only 4 sessionid works (1),(2),(55), and (blank)

I thought that the software will go to row 1, if code=7, then join on User_solici, when done, select distinct (in this case will be session 1 and blank), put this distinct to count (or final file). Done with row 1, go to row 2. This case, it will create 5 count.

Can anyone help me to understand how SQL handle the join (or null) in this case?

Thank you,

Harry

Comment: You can think of it as a `group by` with no aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the DISTINCT clause will only return a single instance of all columns in your select regardless of how many records qualify the criteria.

Your first query actually works given your second assessment of 1, 2, 55 and blank.  But because the blank session has multiple users, THAT is the break in your count.  So, if you did DISTINCT SessionID AND User_Solici you will get the 5 entries I THINK you are looking for.  I would just shift your T1 criteria into the WHERE clause as that has no bearing on the JOIN to T2 table

```
select distinct 
      T1.sessionid,
      T1.User_solici
   from 
      mytable T1 
         join mytable T2
            on T1.User_solici = T2.User_solici
           and T2.code in ('1','2')
   where
      T1.code = '7'
```

Comment: I understand the distinct on Sessionid and User_solici to get 5 count.
But what actually SQL does when I distinct only on Sessionid, I am very curious?


Related to the moving T2.code in ('1','2') inside the join and T1.code out in WHERE. What does it help? I see many do it that way and I am not totally understand the difference between my query and that convention OR Putting both in the WHERE

Thanks a lot,

Harry

Comment: @Harry, SQL just looks at the result of columns for distinct.  It looks at a record, qualifies the condition, then looks in its existing list of prior qualified and says... Do I already have one of these? It doesn't care about the 1 or 2 code as long as the Session is distinct, it doesn't care after that for keeping that one element.